# Drinny fanfic in which Draco joins the Order and marries Ginny

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’m looking for a Draco Malfoy x Ginny Weasley fanfic I read on fanfiction.net in which the Golden Trio take a lot longer than a year to destroy all the Horcruxes, and in that time, Draco joins the Order and marries Ginny. The Golden Trio, particularly Harry, are shocked to find their sister married to Malfoy. I remember it began with them arriving at the Burrow, and the wards detecting them so Draco and I think Bill maybe, go to check it out, and the Golden Trio seem to think Bill must be under the Imperius curse.

Please help me find this fic, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Um, I certainly hope you're not implying Ginny is Harry's sister....